# Inertia moment of $r=3\sin{4\theta}$

Tags: calculus

From my textbook, I knew that the inertia moment of an area ($y=f(x)$) can be found by using this formula:
\begin{equation*}
I_X=\frac{1}{3} \int_{a}^{b} \rho y^3\ dx
\end{equation*}
for case with respect to the $x$, and
\begin{equation*}
I_X=\int_{a}^{b} \rho x^2y\ dx
\end{equation*}
for case with respect to the $y$. $\rho$ is density constant.

I am curious if may be the formula for polar-coordinate is different. It is said (in textbook) that inertia moment of polar is $I_o=I_X+I_Y$, but, how can i determine the $I_X$ and $I_Y$ of $r=3\sin{4\theta}$ if i don't know what should i choose as parameters? and I don't know about the integral boundaries.

Comment: i think the shape of the polar curve looks like flower

Comment: I think $d\theta$ will be variable as we change angle it covers up the whole curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the MOI could be written as $I_z =\int \int r^2 rd{\theta} d{r}$ for one lobe of the curve and the MOI of the whole curve along z axis will be $8I$ .
using perpendicular axis theorem 
$$I_z=I_x +I_y $$ as the figure is symmetrical $$I_x=I_y$$
then $$I_z=2I_x$$